# How would I approach this in blender?

Tags: text, texture, blender

How would I go about creating the Claws text in blender?

[image: Claws Bling]

Comment: There is a Blender Forum in StackExchange where this question belong. https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is better suited for the [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes close it blender is the appropriate place.